# Oracle sql order by column containing symbols

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

How can i order by varchar column containing following values?

```
10/23c abc 1
10/23c abc 5
10/23c abc 3
10/23c abc 2
tx#5- abc 11
tx#5- deb 9
tx#5- cdg 16
tx#5- abc 5
....
```

to following,

```
10/23c abc 1
10/23c abc 2
10/23c abc 3
10/23c abc 5
tx#5- abc 5
tx#5- abc 11 
tx#5- cdg 16
tx#5- deb 9
```

Comment: I suppose that the column always contains 3 substrings separated by a single space and that you want to order first on the 2nd substring and then the numeric value of the 3rd substring?

Comment: @stackmj18 . . . Do the values always have three components separated by spaces?

Comment: Why do you store these values concatenated in one column, when you are obviously interested in its separate parts?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have three components separated by spaces and the last is an integer, you can do:

```
order by regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, 1),
         regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, 2),
         cast(regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, 3) as number)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, only the last component is int after space. Number of components are different.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of components is variable and only the last is numeric, you can simply order on the whole string but adding leading 0's to the last component.

This could be done as follows:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, ' ', -1)) || LPAD(SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ' ', -1) + 1), 8, '0');
```

I.e., extract the whole string up till the last space than add leading 0's to the last part and concatenate the 2 substrings.

**EDIT:**
This of course causes `first second 1` to come after `first second third 2`. This because digits come after letters.
Not sure if that's what you want.

**OTHER EDIT:**
Not sure whether the separator is always a single space or can be multiple.
If so, create an expression that replaces multiple spaces into a single one.
See [Oracle update multiple spaces in a column with a single space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607353/oracle-update-multiple-spaces-in-a-column-with-a-single-space)

**UPDATE:**
The following expression extracts the integer after the last space:

```
SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ' ', -1) + 1)
```

The expression `INSTR(col, ' ', -1)` returns the position of the last space.
After that, take the substring starting from the first character after that last space.

Comment: Hi Robert, how can i extract int after last space?